# Analyze $x^A(1 - x)^B$ divided by $(1 +  x^2)$ with remainder $ax + b$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Assume $A, B \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. If $x^A(1 - x)^B$ is divided by $(1 +
>  x^2)$, the remainder is $ax + b$, show that $a = (\sqrt{2})^B
>  \sin\frac{(2A - B)\pi}{4}$ and $b = (\sqrt{2})^B \cos\frac{(2A -
>  B)\pi}{4}$

So, I guess I have something like:

$$g(x)(1+x^2) = ax + b$$

Without a value to sub in, I am not sure how I proceed. Where should I go with this? I'm not sure how the sin and cos will appear.

Comment: There's some weird typo showing up with "greater than" signs where they have no business being. Can you edit?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: It was from the quote, I don't know why. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F(x)$ be our polynomial. We have
$$F(x)=q(x)(x^2+1)+ax+b.$$
The right substitutions, at least if your course mentions complex variables, are $x=i$ and $x=-i$. Then, for example,
$$b=\frac{1}{2}\left(F(i)+F(-i)\right).$$
Put $F(i)$ and $F(-i)$ in polar form.

Comment: Why are they the right substitutions? Other than perhaps they produce the correct answer. How can you derive these without being told to use them?

Comment: You were yourself looking for a substitution. If for example we were dividing by $(x-1)(x-2)$ instead of $x^2+1$, we would substitute $x=1$ and $x=2$. Here since we know nothing much about what I called $q(x)$, we substitute values for $x$ that will "kill" $q(x)(x^2+1)$, so we plug in the solutions of $x^2+1=0$.

Comment: @stariz77 The idea is that you have no idea what $q(x)$ is unless you compute it. Anyhow, since $q(x)$ is multiplied by $x^2+1$, it is much easier to make $x^2+1=0$, than compute $q(x)$... And if $x^2+1=0$, it is irrelevant what $q$ is , because it is multiplied by $0$...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\ \mathbb R[x]/(x^2+1)\:\! \cong \mathbb C\ $ via $\rm\ f(x) + (x^2+1)\:\mathbb R[x]\: \to\:  f({\it i})$

So, equivalently, compute $\rm\ {\it i}^{\:\!A} (1-{\it i})^B =\: a\:{\it i} + b$